# iOS make button that looks like UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, uinavigationitem

Aside from duplicating the look of UINavigationItem into a custom image file, is there any way to add a button to iOS application that looks like a UINavigationItem?

I have UITableView and would like to have buttons on the right side of each cell for specific actions (1 button per cell, but not all cells have the same buttons). So I was looking to base  this on the behaviour of "Delete" button that shows up when doing swipe-to-delete on table cells, except I would also need the ability to change the color and text of such a button.

What's the best way to do something like this?

Edit: I know I can just duplicate that look in Photoshop and use an image, but that way to change title and colour I have to go back to editing the image every time. Is there any way to make a button that looks like UINavigationItem programmatically, outside of a UINavigationBar?

Comment: Have you tried using a custom cell with a button?

Comment: You can create custom buttons that draw themselves. Have you tried that?

Comment: What does a `UINavigationItem` look like? It's not a UIView. Do you mean `UIBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 0):

The button style I was looking for is UISegmentedControl. It behaves a little bit different than a standard button, but looks a whole lot better. A good alternative to the ugly inflexible UIButton if you don't have hours to spend making buttons in a graphics editor.

```
UISegmentedControl *btn = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"My Button"]];
btn.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
btn.momentary = YES;
btn.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```